# I want to print the value from javascript

Tags: javascript, echo

I am using javascript like this in a webpage.

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
                //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            break;
                    case "checkbox":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                            break;
                    case "select-one":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                            break;
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

you can see, there is 'i' is used in for loop.

Now I want to echo 'i' in php.

what is the way to echo $i?

Comment: You know that javascript is CLIENT-side, and PHP is SERVER-side, so first will php be runned, and then javascript....

Comment: where is $1 in the above code?

Comment: And for javascript, you can use `console.log(i);` to log i. So you get no messagebox, but it will be logged in your browser thing (chrome - F12)

Comment: Why PHP? PHP runs before the page loads.

Comment: @jade, he means var i of javascript, parsed as php variable $

Comment: @Frey: because my web page is in php.

Comment: @Ravneet'Abid' Your webpage is HTML, CSS, and JavaScript by the time it gets to the browser, it does not care that it is .NET, Java, VB, etc.

Comment: @Ravneet'Abid', that is mayby so, but the code posted above is javascript, and as  i mentiod, is javascript an client side script...

Comment: You seem to grossly misunderstand the difference between server-side and client-side code. Perhaps if you read up on that, you would realize that you are taking the wrong approach.

Comment: why would you want to echo that in php? If you just want to see the value of `i` either use `console.log(i)` and look in your browser console (not IE) or, if you want to be annoyed, do `alert(i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use and you will see the result in firebug console or chrome debugger console

```
console.log(i);
```

Comment: like this put it here afetr this line
 `for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    console.log(i);
 `
and then write click on chrome 
then select inspect element fom the menu
a div under will appear select console from it
run your code and you will see the result of i

Comment: @Ravneet'Abid' That line of code goes in your javascript inside the loop. When it runs it will print the value to your browser's console, which is in the developer tools (exactly how to get to it depends on the browser).